# const { require } = require("yargs"); SyntaxError: Identifier 'require' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, visual-studio, cmd

Como van?. Lo que sucede esque cuando intento correr el programa, me sale el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

algunas veces se soluciona por cuestión de magia y otras ni volviendo escribir todo el codigo logra funcionar. No entiendo que sucede.
Espero logren ayudarme y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Estás tratando de importar la función require de yargs, la cual tiene el mismo nombre que [require()](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id) de node.

Comment: Adicionalmente, la función tiene una anotación de deprecación `@deprecated
since version 6.6.0 Use '.demandCommand()' or '.demandOption()' instead`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

es por que `require` es una palabra reservada del lenguaje, puedes ponerle un alias a el módulo que estás cargando de la siguiente manera:

```js
const { require: req } = require('yargs');
```

o

```js
import { require as req } from 'yargs';
```

Comment: Esa sintaxis esta erronea, deberia ser: `const { require: req } = require('yargs')`

Answer (score 0):

Llevo 2 días con ese error. Resulta que hay un bug en VSCode con el auto import.
Aunque tu escribas `const argv = require('yargs')` , si mientras escribes le das sin querer a auto-import cuando te lo sugiere, te va a importar `const { require } = require(“yargs”);`  Lo peor es que aunque lo borres, te lo sigue manteniendo porque te lo está guardando en una especie de buffer. Yo lo solucioné reinstalando VSCode y antes de utilizarlo, desactive el auto-import ( File > preferences > settings > auto import )